# Video player position object div

Tags: javascript, php, css, jwplayer

Looking for some way of repositioning a video player to where it used to be displayed on a page.

The player was called using

```
$object = "<video id='video_player_".$unique_id."'>".JText::_('LOADING_PLAYER')."</video>";
```

however some custom javascript needed to be added to the player and so the code was changed to

```
//$object = "<video id='video_player_".$unique_id."'>".JText::_('LOADING_PLAYER')."</video>";

?>
<div class="videoplayer" align="center">
    <video id='video_player_<?=$unique_id?>'>Loading player...</video>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    var source_folder="";
    var videolist="";
</script>
```

Is there anyway to get the javascript positioned in the same spot as the $object. At the moment the player just appears at the top of the page and not within the columns of the template.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the player with another div, then apply a style to that div.

Something like:

```
<div style="position:absolute:top:0px;left:0px;">
<div class="videoplayer" align="center">
    <video id='video_player_<?=$unique_id?>'>Loading player...</video>
</div>
</div>
```

Maybe that will work.